# Message queuing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, message-queue, .net-4.0

While i was writing a piece of code in C# using ASP.NET i needed to create a message queue to store fault messages. However, I couldn't find the System.Messaging namespace in the namespace library in Visual Studio 2010. Does anyone know how can I use message queuing now?

Comment: I assume you've loaded the reference?

Comment: As a quick trick, an easy way to determine if a reference is loaded without having to leave the line of code you are on, is to press Ctrl + period after typing in the type name.  If a window appears with an assembly name, the assembly is loaded -- and you can select it.  Otherwise, you'll have to load the assembly into the project references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core System.Messaging classes are in their own assembly: you have to add a reference to that assembly to use them. (You should use the version from the Global Assembly Cache found on the ".NET" tab in the Add Reference dialog.)